# Problema en envío masivo de correos electrónicos con mail de PHP

Tags: php, mysql, cron, mail

He creado un php para una tarea CRON para enviar correos electrónicos a una serie de Usuarios registrados, pero cuando envío los correos si hay mas de un Usuario se envía el correo n veces acumulado a cada envío, por cada Usuario se va acumulando los anteriores y así consecutivamente, entonces el usuario al final recibe muchos correos donde en realidad solo debería recibir 1. Estoy usando un while para iterar cada usuario y tomar el email del usuario para enviarlo. Algo así:

```
    do {$conta_Cursor=$conta_Cursor+1;
                $dni = $row_Cursor['dni'];
                $nombre = $row_Cursor['nombre'];
                $email = $row_Cursor['email'];
                 
                $para    = "$email"; 
                $titulo  = "USUARIO datos de : " .$nombre ; 
                $mensaje .= 
        "Hola,
        Acorde a tu decisión de CONFIRMAR tus datos, hemos procedido a actualizar los datos según lo 
        indicado en el Asunto de este correo.
        USUARIO : $nombre
        DNI     : $dni
        En cumplimiento a tu autorización, dada en su momento, a que formasen parte de la base de 
         datos de la Empresa, a ser protegidos y utilizados conforme L.O.P.D 2018 actualmente en      
        vigor, procedemos a su actualización de nuestros sistemas.
           Un cordial Saludo.
           El Gerente";
                $cabeceras = "From: Gerente@empresax.es\r\n";       
                mail($para,utf8_decode($titulo),utf8_decode($mensaje), $cabeceras);
                mail(ClearAddresses);
                        }
                while ($row_Cursor = mysqli_fetch_array($Cursor_Usuarios)); 
            } 
        else
            { echo "¡ No se ha encontrado ningún registro Usuarios !"; }
```

Comment: Si son pocos usuarios estará rapido de iterar, pero imagina que sean unos 20 mil registros ó más, en esos casos es mejor crear una clase job, hacer colas/queues de los mails y preparar/configurar tu servidor para estos casos, la parte del cron es solo cuando esta calendarizado y ejecutas el servicio cada n fecha

Answer (score 0):

El codigo que compartes esta algo incompleto, pero intenta cambiarlo por un ciclo for de la siguiente manera, de esa forma visualizar la iteración de una forma más clara:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($row_Cursor); $i++)
{
        $dni = $row_Cursor['dni'];
        $nombre = $row_Cursor['nombre'];
        $email = $row_Cursor['email'];
         
        $para    = "$email"; 
        $titulo  = "USUARIO datos de : " .$nombre ; 
        $mensaje = "Hola, USUARIO: $nombre , DNI: $dni;

        $cabeceras = "From: Gerente@empresax.es\r\n";   

        mail($para,utf8_decode($titulo),utf8_decode($mensaje), $cabeceras);
        mail(ClearAddresses);
}
```

Comment: Gracias Jonathan, el bucle funciona correctamente con el do... while, la pregunta a lo que no está funcionando y por lo que inicié el chat, es que si hay mas de un correo para cada envío va acumulando a partir del primer correo enviado a los siguientes de forma incremental, es decir el texto del correo se va repitiendo de forma progresiva..

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por las respuestas, YA LO HE RESUELTO, cuando pueda cerraré la pregunta, la solución era limpiar(borrar contenido del mensaje) después de cada envío, se esa manera el bucle de enviar correos funciona correctamente, a cada Usuario le envía un mensaje distinto y no acumula el texto de los anteriores...

```
        $cabeceras = "From: -----------.es\r\n";       
        $cabeceras .= "Bcc: --------.com\r\n";                                     
        mail($para,utf8_decode($titulo),utf8_decode($mensaje), $cabeceras);
    
        $mensaje ="";
        }
        while ($row_Cursor = mysqli_fetch_array($Cursor_Usuarios));
```

Comment: O sea, la solución era no usar `$mensaje .=` al asignar el mensaje. :)  Trata de no "cerrar" la pregunta y más bien marca la respuesta como aceptada mañana

Answer (score 0):

RESUELTO, la solución era limpiar(borrar contenido del mensaje) después de cada envío, se esa manera el bucle de enviar correos funciona correctamente, a cada Usuario le envía un mensaje distinto y no acumula el texto de los anteriores...